# Как заставить recyclerview обновлять данные при их обновлении в БД на firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Я написал программу, которая получает данные из БД на `firebase` и через адаптер выводит их в  `recyclerview`. Программа работает, но при обновлении данных в БД данные на экране не обновляются. Как правильно это сделать? Блок кода, отвечающий за получение данных, оставляю внизу:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://fireapp-12b506.firebaseio.com/museums");
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            Museum m = dataSnapshot.getValue(Museum.class);
             museums.add(m);
             museumAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {




        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```